# Selected column is not ordered when using .sort_values()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting

Practising some ordering with df. The main idea here is order only the first column without affecting the `"Dos"` and `"Tres"` column in `df3`.

Have tried this but it doesn´t work so I have no clue what to do. `df2` performs a normal sort while the other one remains the same.

```
list_of_dicts_2 = {"Uno":[4,3,6,2,1,5], "Dos": [3,5,7,8,12,4],"Tres": [9,8,6,5,3,1]}
df2= pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts_2)
print("SECOND DF")
print(df2)
df2= df2.sort_values(by = ["Uno"])
print(df2)
#To do this, alterate the order of all columns.
df3= pd.DataFrame(list_of_dicts_2)
print("THIRD DF")
print(df3)
df3["Uno"]= df3["Uno"].sort_values()
print(df3)
```

Expected output:

```
list_of_dicts_answer = {"Uno":[1,2,3,4,5,6], "Dos": [3,5,7,8,12,4],"Tres": [9,8,6,5,3,1]}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes because the pandas assignation works index-wise. When you do

```
df3['Uno'] = df3['Uno'].sort_values()
```

Pandas matches the sorted values (`1, 2,...,`) using both `series` indexes (this is, it tries to assign values based on their index), so you end up getting the original dataframe without changes. To prevent this, don't assign a `series` but rather the sorted values itself:

```
df3["Uno"] = df3["Uno"].sort_values().values
print(df3)
>>  Uno Dos Tres
    1   3   9
    2   5   8
    3   7   6
    4   8   5
    5   12  3
    6   4   1
```